# Partition recovery after delete with cfdisk

Tags: partitioning

I have to hdds in my PC. I used to have Windows Vista (one current installation, one old) on both of them. I was trying to install Linux on my old windows disk. I backuped all data and started Linux installation. But I used cfdisk on wrong disk (main vista instalation that I didn't backuped).

I saw that before any file was copied, but unfortunately after i saved changes in cfdisk (I only deleted partitions not crated any new).

What is best way to recovery my data? If possible I would like to recovery full install and don't have to install OS again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is create new partitions in EXACTLY the same layout as they were previously. Make sure to not reformat, and all your data should still be there. Creating/deleting partitions simply edits the partition table, which is stored at the beginning of your disk. As long as you don't reformat, the actual data on the disk stays untouched.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I now theory, but how to find my previous partition layout?

Answer (score 3):

Try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). That page also contains links to TestDisk's documentation.